# Getting "Invalid Floating Point" error with ActiveX Control in Delphi

Tags: delphi, activex

A vendor has developed an ActiveX control in Microsoft C++.  The ActiveX worked fine when they were using the 16bit version of the compiler.  The control does not work when compiled using the 32bit version within the Delphi2007/D7 environments.  If you drop a control on a form and run it throws an "Floating Point Error".

It is a Delphi issue.  We are able to use the ActiveX in other applications.

Anyone ever have a similar problem or have a solution for this?

Comment: Thanks - I am checking out this setting.  Will let you know if I can get it to work.

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like an FPU problem - check out Set8087CW in Delphi's help file.

Comment: Absolutely agree. Same thing happens with Quicktime ActiveX control.

Comment: Thank you both for your answers.  Turns this was the solution.  

For what it is worth, the ActiveX was by a company called Pictometry.  This is a highly graphical software product.